# dcdiag fails with SystemLog errors

Tags: active-directory, diagnostic

My domain has 2 DC's and when I run dciag on one I get this error:

```
Starting test: SystemLog
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x00002716
            Time Generated: 08/06/2023   08:05:37
            Event String:
            DCOM got error "2147944122" from the computer domctl.MYDOMAIN.COM when attempting to activate the server:
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x00002716
            Time Generated: 08/06/2023   08:05:38
            Event String:
            DCOM got error "2147944122" from the computer domctl.MYDOMAIN.COM when attempting to activate the server:
         ......................... DOMCTL-K failed test SystemLog
```

I can't find any explanation of what this means or how to solve it.

Comment: `DCOM got error "2147944122" from the computer domctl.MYDOMAIN.COM when attempting to activate the server`   On Aug 6, there was an error activating a COM+ "server". Usually represented by a Guid, and frequently related to WMI. This sometimes means there is insufficient network connectivity, meaning one or more of the many ports required are/were blocked. But given that there isn't an actual problem stated and no additional information it could be any of the hundreds of COM+ services in use.